# Can you explain this Mathematica $Assumptions behaviour?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Consider the following three lines of Mathematica code and note that input line 1 and 3 are exactly the same (This is the smallest piece of code I found to demonstrate this behaviour).

```
>> Integrate[Exp[-a^2] Sin[2 p] ((a^2 + b^2) + b*Cos[p] + a*Sin[p]), {p, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
0

>> $Assumptions = {t > 0};
>> Integrate[Exp[-a^2] Sin[2 p] ((a^2 + b^2) + b*Cos[p] + a*Sin[p]), {p, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]

8/3 Sqrt[a^2+b^2] E^-a^2
```

Note that the integral should yield 0, like in Mathematica's first answer. The assumption I enter has apparently nothing to do with the integration. Is this a bug (I use Mathematica 8.0)?

Even stranger, if I split the integral into a sum of 2 or 3 integrals, each of them yields 0. Same thing if I take parts out of the integral which do not depend on p.

For me it looks like a bug but if there is something I'm missing, please let me know.

Comment: I can reproduce it in a fresh kernel in 8.0.4. `t` doesn't even appear in your expression, it looks like a bug.  You could contact Wolfram Support with the problem, so they can fix it.

Comment: I filed a bug report. Let's see what the support team is saying. Thanks.

Comment: Appears to be fixed in a development Mathematica. (Am hoping it stays that way.)

Comment: Got an answer from the Wolfram Support team: "It does appear that Integrate is not behaving properly, and I have
forwarded an incident report to our developers with the information
you provided.

In addition to the workarounds you already have, I found that moving
the Exp[-a^2] outside the Integrate also allows Integrate to find
the correct result."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mathematica 7.0.1 the result is 0,  while in 8.0.4  we get

```
8/3 Sqrt[a^2+b^2] E^-a^2
```

Thus it has to be a bug, even worse it is an error. Fortunately, one can easily verify the result without a computer, but in case of a more involved integral it would be a major problem.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I filed a bug report (see above).

Comment: It is a good idea to keep elder versions while updating software, at least such a comprehensive system as M. Numerous times I had to compare output in different versions.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been solved. In 9.0 version, both give results 0.